# ActiveRecord - Include field from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Currently I habe three models

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_leagues
  has_many :teams, through: :team_leagues
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :league
end

class TeamLeague < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  belongs_to :team
end
```

And I can retrieve results with e.g

```
leagues_with_teams = League.includes(:teams).find_by_id(1)
```

The team_leagues Table has an extra column "status". So I would like to include it in my results to habe something like that:

```
{
  league_id: 1
  teams: [
    {team_id: 1,status: 0},
    {team_id: 2,status: 5}

  ]
}
```

how can I do that?

Comment: well you can certainly wrestle a query into producing the result you're looking for. But I'm lazy and my approach would be to just `Team.where(league_id: 1)` and work with what that gives you.

Comment: I am just wondering activerecord hasn't standart way to do that..

Comment: you can use an ActiveModel::Serializer to create the representation you seek